# Ошибка при авторизации в VK через приложение на node.js

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api, express

Добрый день, товарищи!

Возникла проблема - не могу справиться с авторизацией через ВК в своем приложении (`node.js` + `express.js` + `passport.js`). При попытке авторизации браузер показывает следующее сообщение:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"redirect_uri is
>   incorrect, check application domain in the settings page"}

Все делал по примеру c данной страницы: [**Passport-VKontakte**](https://github.com/stevebest/passport-vkontakte)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Убедитесь, что у вас адрес домена в redirect_url и базовый домен в приложении (в вконтакте) совпадают.

Comment: На самом деле была проблема в другом - в ВК я создал приложение не того типа (standalone вместо веб-сайта). Ну и соответственно, не был указан домен.

Answer (score 6):

Если кто-то в будущем столкнется с этой проблемой, возможно вам поможет следующее:

1. Убедитесь, что тип созданного вами приложения во Вконтакте поддерживает стороннюю авторизацию: standalone или веб-сайт
2. Для standalone приложений убедитесь, что в настройках приложения взведена галочка open API. Пусть вас не смущает, что open API не имеет ничего общего с Oauth2.
3. Если вы размещаете приложение на кириллическом домене, в настройках должен быть указан домен приложения именно в кириллическом наборе, а не в punycode. Да, фактически вариант punycode должен быть тождественным кириллице, но во Вконтакте вот так вот сложилось.

Answer (score 4):

Мне не удалось решить проблему вот так:

Нужно в настройках приложения Вконтакте **сделать пустым поле *Доверенный redirect URI:*.** 
После этого у меня все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании API в мобильном приложении заработало после того как стал передавать пустой redirect_uri.
Пример запроса:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=&response_type=token&scope=0&v=5.92
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы прокинул порт с помощью ngrok.
Заполнил адрес сайта(с указанием протокола) и базовый домен(без указания протокола).
Доверенный redirect URI оставил пустым.